# Why would you NOT upvote the question that you are bothering to answer?

Tags: discussion

Often I receive valid answers to my valid questions, but my question remains with zero votes, i.e user providing the answer did not find it necessary to upvote my question (yet wasted time to provide an answer).

I'm not talking about spam/homework/trivial/somehow-invalid questions. I'm talking about "ordinary" question that deserves (and hence - receives) the answer. I believe that if the question is "good enough" to provide answers, it is already useful to the community (tiny tiny bit at least), at the very least - it should be from the perspective of the user providing answer (otherwise, why bother answering and why not close it as duplicate/spam/etc).

I'm not saying that users should always upvote questions they answer, but for the most part, I don't think why they shouldn't.

So... What's the phenomenon here?..

P.S.: An example qeustion: [How do I generate script for LocalDB database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905239/how-do-i-generate-script-for-localdb-database/)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/509/204841

Comment: There's an up vote and a down vote on that question so while at least 2 didn't vote up, at least 2 of them didn't down vote either. If they didn't vote at all that implies they didn't feel that strongly either way about the quality or usefulness of the question to vote on it. I can see a user feeling 'meh' about a question but not also thinking it doesn't deserve an answer.

Comment: *"Don't you contradict yourself when you provide answer to the question that you find not useful?"* Only if you don't know what Stack Overflow actually is. The answerer still can post an answer to help ___you___, although (s)he doesn't think that it is helpful for anybody else.

Comment: Just because *you* think a question is a good question doesn't mean everyone else is obligated to agree with you.  If you think the question is good, you can upvote it, if other people think it's not, they don't have to.  Each person gets to determine *their own* vote, not everyone else's.

Comment: You wouldn't upvoted any time you don't feel like it, and that's fine. Upvoting is optional, nobody is compelled to vote. People are completely free to use the site without voting at all.

Comment: I have the same question as you. I can't understand why someone would think a question is good enough to answer but not good enough to upvote.

Comment: Related (but, oddly, highly upvoted): ‘‘[Why answer a question not worth your upvote?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3133/23408)’’

Answer (score 23):

You wouldn't upvote the question for the same reason you wouldn't upvote *any* question, it doesn't meet the stated upvote criteria of, "shows research effort; it is useful and clear".  Note that only one of those is a reason to close or flag the question, so your statement that the question should be closed instead simply doesn't apply.

"it is already useful to the community" That the question has gotten an answer doesn't mean that it's useful to the community.  There are *millions* of questions here with answers that aren't actually useful questions.