# What can be improved with my questions to prevent 0 votes?

Tags: discussion, support, upvotes, post-ban, zero-voted-posts

My account was recently banned from asking more Stack Overflow question on grounds of having too many "zero-voted" questions. I'm not sure how to go about getting more upvotes, however. I went through my history and while there are questions which could've benefited from more research or more focus, a good majority of them were specific and asked after I exhausted other resources.

It seems to me that the zero-votes are less about the quality of the question and more about Stack Overflow users simply not caring to up vote. Moreover, the more niche a question gets, the more likely this effect occurs. If this is true, then I have no idea how to combat it, as it would be a systematic problem of Stack Overflow, not the user.

Comment: This is a good question. Users are encouraged to only ask a new question as a last resort, but that often means, if a user is good at doing their own research, the only questions they ever ask are very niche questions which few people are likely to encounter (hence the lack of widely-available information).

Comment: Of OP's 9 most-recent 0-vote questions, 8 have less than 100 views; most have less than 50. I think that should be taken into account in the question ban.

Comment: If everyone followed that principal of only asking a question as a last resort, that'd be the only kind of question we have and they'd likely get more votes.

Comment: Looks like you've got some votes that have moved you out of the ban...

Comment: Yes. however, I think that this is an issue that may be more prevalent than expected. It might be worth discussing further.

Comment: *on grounds of having too many "zero-voted" questions* Are you sure? A couple of your questions with a score of zero *do* have votes, they just had the same number of up votes and down votes.

Comment: I have noticed people who aggressively answer all questions in an unfrequented tag - even going so far as to go into the package and fix a bug - but refuses to upvote any questions at all. Seems rather unfair to me. Any question that takes a significant amount of your time to answer ought to get an upvote from you I would think. People like that don't realize they are actually hurting the tag that they love.

Comment: @MikeWise this was just discussed recently - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351716/why-would-you-not-upvote-the-question-that-you-are-bothering-to-answer. Converting so-so question into up-vote worthy one is much harder than answering...

Comment: Asking a question that doesn't get down votes is hard enough, let alone getting upvotes. I'm surprised there is a ban for this.

Comment: Maybe a C++ or a JavaScript user doesn't realize that, but OPs and answerers that deal with very low-popularity tags get 10, maybe 20 views per question. And people simple don't upvote, as if it was paid. That being said, I agree with [Nathan's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351820/what-can-be-improved-with-my-questions-to-prevent-0-votes?cb=1#comment488873_351820), the number of views should be taken into account.

Comment: This is the basic design flaw of stack overflow: it's not a site about answering questions, it's a collection of (sometimes) interesting trivia about code, which is reasonably searchable, but usually only by those who already know the answers. The restrictions on asking the question you actually care about means the site is basically locking out new users, which is a problem for the long-term viability of the model.

Comment: @JonKiparsky I don't understand - 'is reasonably searchable, but usually only by those who already know the answers' ..umm.. why would those people search, then?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Ah, you understand perfectly then. Why, indeed, would they search?

Comment: Also, 'restrictions on asking the question you actually care about means the site is basically locking out new users' - there is nothing stopping the new users answering questions.

Comment: @JonKiparsky well, I tend to search when I don't know the answers, (though I use Google: it's a better search tool than the SO search box).

Comment: You can ask on Meta so people will see your questions. =p @NathanArthur While this might be a good question for "niche tag" users, all of the OP's 0 questions are in [tag:c++] or [tag:java].

Comment: Honestly I can relate to this. I'm worried about this happening to me, if it wasn't for that one guy in chat upvoting my matlab answer I'd still be on my way to an answer ban for zero vote answers on relatively low view questions.

Comment: Well, @jrh did you ignored 11 warnings the system gave you?

Comment: @Braiam Nope. This is more of a (really) long term concern. Also, by the way guys, according to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345619/4975230) zero vote posts DO count towards a ban, unless something changed?

Comment: @jrh aren't you reading Shog's answer just below? The bold text?

Comment: @Braiam Check the link, in the post I linked in the comment earlier the OP's answer score wasn't negative, it was 0.3; though this is all kind of in theory anyway because the post said that this the threshold is really only known by SE.

Comment: @jrh again, guesses. Horse mouth > everyone else that is not a horse.

Comment: @Braiam yep, we're on the same page. I've been following this for a while and I've got about 10 or 15 meta posts on this topic bookmarked, there's a good chance Shog will say "it's proprietary" but I figure it can't hurt to try.

Comment: @Braiam I see what you mean, I think I might have stopped following that question before Martin revealed that it really was due to deleted answers. I had to read the comment thread a few more times before it struck me as a real, official answer to the question. It might be better to post that sort of thing as an answer instead of a comment so it stands out.

Comment: @jrh it's *Martijn*, and Shog [already pointed you to that comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351820/what-can-be-improved-with-my-questions-to-prevent-0-votes?cb=1#comment489284_351877). Well, and Braiam too before that. I guess I just don't understand what you don't understand.

Comment: @AndrasDeak don't worry about it, this has gone on long enough and I'll just assume Shog is saying that it's okay to ask and answer low view questions. Though FYI Martijn's [new comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345617/im-very-uncertain-why-my-questions-on-so-were-deemed-low-quality-and-my-account/345619#comment489316_345619) now just said "there is no official answer, even moderators don't know how the quality post ban algorithm works."

Comment: @jrh that is _definitely_ what he's been saying. Consistently. Everything he has said keeps saying that "lack of votes don't lead to a question ban, downvotes do". Every meta question suggesting otherwise ends up revealing that OP has a bunch of downvotes and insufficient upvotes to go with them. This is all consistent with **MARTIJN**'s [note the **J**] comment that the _specifics_ of the system are unknown. But you need downvotes to get banned. If nobody votes on your posts, you don't. Get. Banned. (And before you do, you start seeing warning all over the place.) OK, promise I'm done here:)

Comment: Geez, that's embarrassing. How did I miss the J? I work with a Martin and it must just be out of habit.

Answer (score 33):

I don't know where you got the idea that you were banned because of zero-scored posts.

You were [warned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow/231118#231118) at least 11 times when posting a question that your *previous* questions hadn't been well-received. Several of your past questions were downvoted, at least one of them *heavily* - this hurts. **Zero-scored questions do not contribute to a ban**, but they don't move you away from it either - if you're consistently posting negatively-scored questions more often than positively-scored ones, you're probably gonna end up banned eventually.

Hence the warnings. Please don't ignore them next time!

Comment: Me: "*Wow, the system is awful, we have to fix it!*" --> "*Oh, the system is working perfectly!*". Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: \*reads comments\* I'm sure it wasn't like that... \*reads answer\* Yep, it wasn't like that.

Comment: BTW Shog, don't moderators have access to this data? Jon comment threw me off at first because it looked like he did checkout and didn't find anything that explains the ban.

Comment: Gotta remember to look for it.

Comment: "Zero-scored questions do not contribute to a ban" -- I don't quite follow, [wasn't this due to zero vote questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345617/im-very-uncertain-why-my-questions-on-so-were-deemed-low-quality-and-my-account/345619#345619) Or did something in the system change?

Comment: @jrh that's a guess, not the horse mouth. [Read Martijn comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345617/im-very-uncertain-why-my-questions-on-so-were-deemed-low-quality-and-my-account/345619#comment458014_345619).

Comment: @Braiam Yep, I know. I'm wondering if Shog can provide more clarification than Martin.

Comment: Well... I could provide more details, but I'd say Martijn made that crystal clear already.

Comment: @Shog9 Fair enough, I'd recommend editing the help center for [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) and [A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) bans to make this more clear. I'd prefer to see something less vague than the "or" in "... if they have a significant number of heavily down-voted, **zero-voted, or** deleted posts."

Comment: @jrh my go-to reference [has been this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311810/can-self-censoring-end-up-with-a-question-ban) on which Shog's answer said basically the same thing as this one, just less clearly (because it wasn't concerning zero-score posts). I suspect that this falls a bit under the "let's keep specific ban details somewhat fuzzy to prevent gaming the system". Then again I vaguely remember seeing a specific formula to how deleted/closed/downvoted posts matter in something...although that might have been for a "well-received" status for a badge. Can't remember.

Comment: @Braiam One of the first things I do is check a user's history when they raise a meta post about bans whether from disputed audits or system imposed. And yes, mods do have that information, and I could see they've been warned 11 times about low quality contributions. To me, it looked liked the user was asking a genuine question that's useful and not necessarily user specific and throwing in "You've been warned 11 times already" would not be useful and bias things.

Comment: @Jon I'm afraid OP's question starting with '*My account was recently banned from asking more Stack Overflow question on grounds of having too many "zero-voted" questions.*' with no remark about those 11 warnings (or existing poo posts at least) tripped me up too:)

Comment: The only important guidance in those help articles for folks who've hit the ban, @jrh, is "**edit**". Very few people do it, but they should. Exhaustive, precise details on the formulas used to enact the ban do nothing but distract from that, which is why we see so many questions on meta seeking exhaustive, precise details and so few about how to edit questions such that others can find and understand them.

Comment: Yes, I've been getting warnings ever since a low voted question a few years ago, but even though I tried to keep my questions higher quality since then, no one was up voting them, and thus the warning never went away. My questions still stands then - how do you prevent zero voted questions?

Comment: @Shog9 when I clicked the link on the ban which showed me the justification for it, one of the reasons was too many "zero-voted questions", and since I didn't get any negatively voted questions since the warnings started appearing, I assumed it was because of that. Unfortunately I can't screenshot it anymore, since the ban was lifted.

Comment: Should have linked to this, @jeanluc: https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans - the "zero-voted" bit is a red herring; I'll revise it when I'm back at a computer.