# Should an answer ban happen when there are too many zero-score posts?

Tags: discussion, answers, post-ban, zero-voted-posts

The [Help Center section explaining question bans](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) states that zero-score questions might lead to a question ban, but I wasn't able to find something similar for answers.

I ask this because I found an user having (at the moment of asking) 200 answers. Absolutely no problem with this, but he had less than 40 upvoted or accepted answers (20% of them are considered useful by other users). Another thing to note is that the user achieved 15 answers/day for the past three days (are the number of answers limited to 15?) and in my opinion some of them are low quality or duplicates. Should this user still be allowed to post answers given this facts?

Note: A very important fact was pointed in comment: this system might affect users that respond in low traffic questions. I agree with this, but the scenario I am talking about is happening on the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag.

Comment: Low answer upvote rate, by itself, does not necessarily indicate a bad user. Sometimes it just means he answers on questions with low rep users. That's why we have things like Unsung Hero. Can't speak to the quality of this particular user, just in general.

Comment: Since the algorithm isn't public, I don't think anyone can say that this issue isn't addressed (at least in some fashion)

Comment: @SandPiper I agree somehow with you, but I still think that a ratio like this indicates some answers posted in a hurry and for the moment, rather for long term, thing that should lead to an answer ban in my opinion.

Comment: @IulianPopescu It can also indicate someone answering questions in niche topics without a lot of traffic, which *isn't* a bad thing.  It's not always easy to distinguish the two.

Comment: First of all, this would work agains the "Unsung Hero" badge and it would punish users working on low traffic tag, or on questinos where OP either just write a comment that the answer was helpful or just accepts it. it should be at least -1, not 0 scored.

Comment: I agree that this would be wrong for low traffic question, but this answers are on `Android` tag which generates some traffic daily. It was my mistake that I didn't think and mentioned about this. I will update the question to include this information

Comment: @Tom There is a *big* difference between 25% of your answers being 0 scored and 80% of your answers being 0 scored, and also a big difference between 10 zero scored answers and 160 zero scored answers, so saying that the situation the OP describes is problematic isn't contradictory to the badge.

Comment: @Tom also it doesn't work against Unsung Hero, because that badge only considers answers that are accepted.

Comment: I undersand from your downvotes that you think that I'm wrong or some other reason and I respect that, but I would really like to share with us your thoughts on this because I personally think that things like this decrease the quality of SO.

Comment: @IulianPopescu you may be over analyzing the `paying special attention to those that score 0 or less` statement.  That does not mean that a lot of zero score questions will result in a ban.  It just means that fixing those questions can help get you unbanned.  There is a difference in meaning.  [Very relevant answer form Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351820/what-can-be-improved-with-my-questions-to-prevent-0-votes/351877#351877) elsewhere on meta

Comment: *I still think that a ratio like this indicates some answers posted in a hurry and for the moment, rather for long term* - But if this is happening in a high traffic tag then why aren't these answers getting down votes instead of ignored, assuming that by zero score you mean 0 votes and not an equal number of up and down votes?

Comment: *in my opinion some of them are low quality or duplicates* Did you down vote any of these? (Don't serial vote but did you vote on any of them?) Were the duplicates simply posted at the same time as other answers or do they appear to be plagiarism? Raise a flag for moderator attention if it looks like they're copy/pasting other user's content.

Comment: @BSMP post explicitly calls out the reason for lack of downvotes - "is happening on the android tag" which has very "flexible" quality bar from what I've seen...

Comment: The more I am reading about answer bans/question bans in the latest time, the more I get scared.

Comment: @Christian Anecdotally speaking, we see *very* few false positives on question/answer bans. I don't think I've *ever* seen one. So if you're making positive contributions, you really have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @BSMP, regarding your first statement: I don't have an answer for that, but one guess is that the `Android` community might not be as implicated in self moderation as others, resulting in the fact that the post are not downvoted. Regarding the second statement: I didn't vote, but I raised 6-7 flags for duplicates (all helpful) and I still have around 10 other answers that are duplicates. One important note is that I let some comments to the user regarding the duplicates, but I was completly ignored.

Comment: These being said, I beleive that I waisted the time of some mod to take care of some issues that could be avoided by having a system that tells you: "Hey, we found that you posted a lots of answers in the past few days and only some of them were upvoted. Please improve the quality of your answers or something." I recognize that a ban might not be the best option here, but is hard to mantain the quality of some posts when a user posts faster than 10 others can read.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, can you please elaborate what you meant? I'm not really sure that I properly understood it.

Comment: @IulianPopescu from what I've seen in "android" tag it is used  "I use Android phone, so my question will only get 'android' tag" :) (maybe it is not really as bad, but I've seen strictly Java/C#/JavaScript questions tagged with just 'android' probably because OP could have used it on Android device). And voting I've seen in that tag somewhat reflects that arbitrary set of "allowed" questions making posts less likely to get downvotes. (This is my personal opinion based on several visits of the tag and in no way scientifically verified behavior).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The whole basis for your question is based on a completely false premise.  The help center says

> Edit all of your questions, paying special attention to those that score 0 or less

I'm not sure how you interpret that to mean that 0-scored questions contribute to the ban.  [Shog9 is on the record to say exactly the opposite](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351820/what-can-be-improved-with-my-questions-to-prevent-0-votes/351877#351877).  It is true that zero-scored answers don't help you with regards to the ban, but as Shog9 says, they will not contribute to them either.

---

But to your point of people leaving mass quantities of zero-scored answers, it is going to have to be looked at on a case-by-case basis.  You could be leaving low quality answers in downvote adverse tags, or you could have one or both of the following:

- Maybe someone answers a lot in low traffic tags or tags that are stingy with upvotes
- Maybe someone answers a lot of old questions (with fresh ideas) but don't get enough visibility to get upvotes right away

How would you measure these against the people constantly and continually throw up garbage to try to get a few points.  That's why people should use their downvotes and not expect others to do it.

---

In light of [your comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354845/should-an-answer-ban-happen-when-there-are-too-many-zero-score-posts/354871#comment503298_354871), I think the term "answer ban" is what triggered the confusion.  The post-ban itself is a ban that never expires.  To "earn one", you have to post some really bad questions (or answers), or to have an extended history of content that was not well received (i.e. downvoted).  Since your scenario has a high volume & high rate of unknown quality content (a massive amount of zero-scored posts), you probably don't want to consider a true post ban, since they are tough to recover from and you don't really know if the content is truly low quality, or just low voted.

Rather you'd be looking at a graduated rate limit of some kind.  In this scenario, you have to make some decisions on thresholds, but you could restrict someone from posting more than `x` answers within the last `y` time units (hours, days, etc) that did not receive any upvotes.  This could certainly slow someone down and force them to think about answer **quality** not quantity.

Comment: I think that I was not clear enough. I didn't say that this behaviour should be banned, but rather I was posting a possible solution to handle a large number of answers that are not well received by the community. One of my mistake is that I didn't clearly said that I don't have a problem with the number of  zero-score questions, but with their frequency. This makes the problem of low traffic tags to be almost impossible and the second point to be a really really edge case.

Comment: In the end, I don't have a solution, because I start to think that the comunnity doesn't see this as a problem. But I am sure that if somebody decides that this will became a problem for the quality of StackOverflow, then there are enough bright minds that can colaborate in order to fix this issue covering all the possbile edge cases.

Comment: So you are probably more talking about a rate limit more than anything. If the user is blasting out too many possible low quality answers - you want to slow them down, not ban them completely. That might make more sense than an outright answer ban.  I've amended my answer to include something more to address your concerns (if i am reading you correctly)

Answer (score 5):

I would personally have to look at the answers themselves in order to form a qualitative opinion on the matter. Hard statistical facts just isn't enough to tell whether or not the behavior is abusive or otherwise undesired.

You do not disclose much detail about these answers. One of the first things I'd look at is how many of the answers have a **negative score** and not just those that lack upvotes. Let's not forget that the voting system is the best measure to determine quality posts from problematic posts.

There's a big difference between someone with 80% of their answers having **zero score**, and someone with 80% of their answers having **negative score**.

There can be many reasons for the lack of up-votes:

- The answers are of an unpopular or outdated technology (e.g Flash), it is very possible that the answers just don't get enough attention to get an up-vote anymore.
- The answers are for an old question which doesn't attract enough of views to get an up-vote.
- The answers are correct and useful, but are misformatted and hard to read.
- People chose to up-vote other, better answers.
- The asker doesn't have enough reputation to up-vote.

...the list is endless.

---

Take a look at the [*When should I vote up?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and [*When should I vote down?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) sections of the help page:

> **When should I vote up?**
>
> Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!

and

> **When should I vote down?**
>
> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

Note that it says *"especially useful"* for up-voting and *"egregiously sloppy"* , *"no-effort-expended"* and "*dangerous*" for down-voting. Perhaps the user in question has a tendency to post answers that falls between those descriptions, which is not very uncommon to see in my experience.

Of course, if the majority of answers fit the latter category, then just flag those answers for "low quality" and move on. If you want, you could post a comment with a link to [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), if you want to help out.

Given enough flags though, may result in an [answer ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans).

Comment: Very good points here and I agree that without more concrete information is hard to make a decision. However, having answered 50 question in the last 3 days and scoring only 10-15 questions might show some low quality answeres. Regarding the category of the answer, maybe a solution should be found for the zero scored answers, because in my opinion these answers are decreasing SO posts quality.

Comment: @IulianPopescu I don't think it's fair to just look at *"% of answers having received up-votes"*. A better way to look at it would be *"% of answers not having a negative score"*, for the reasons I explained

Comment: There are ~10% answers with negative score. And I agree that the zero score might not be the best indicator, but a lot of answers with zero score in a short time period might indicate some bad posts. What is your opinion on that?

Comment: My *personal* opinion? I think 10% is high, but certainly not high enough to warrant a ban nor a warning. What I would do if I were you is to flag the ones that are problematic and perhaps post a comment as to *why* it's bad and how said user can improve the quality of their posts.

Answer (score 2):

I would disagree with this. Simply because an answer does not have upvotes does not make it a bad answer.

1) Answers on a new user's post (very low rep,) the OP does not have the option to upvote the answer, even if it is a perfect and correct answer.

2) Sometimes an answer will be correct and well thought out but a second answer incorporates that information and elaborates upon the issue even further. These answers are usually the ones that receive the votes, but it does not make the original answer 'wrong.'

3) Zero vote questions are the singular and the answers are the many. Every question will be read if you navigate to that question, but not every answer will be. I usually stop at the first few most upvotes answers, again, doesn't make other answers any less valid. This is a case **for zero vote question bans and against zero vote answer bans**

4) Duplicated and low quality answers can be (and should be) flagged. There already exists a way to handle these issues and **these are the issues that should lead to an answer ban**

Comment: First, thanks for your opinions. I agree with the first because it happen to me a few times, but most of the new users are happy to mark you answer as accepted if it was helpful for them. 2nd point is valid, but I think that if you post 100 answers and other 100 peoples are building a better answer based on yours, your answers still have a quality problem. Regarding

Comment: 3, it's a soft ground, but I will say my thoughts: I'm not the best supporter of the idea to post an answer to a question if there are already a few answers because there is a good chance that what you want to say is already covered, making your answers useless (happend to me a few times while reviewing the Late Answer queue). 4th It's hard to review so many answers.

Comment: I would agree that there may be a quality problem with copious amounts of 0 voted questions even if the questions are not technically 'wrong.' But a ban based on a less explicit answer set would be bad. sometimes a **minimal** answer is all that is needed, but an extrapolated answer has a better flavor to it that will help more people, which will gain more votes. I concede that new users will (sometimes) accept a good answer without the upvote, but your proposition only takes into consideration the 0 upvotes. Based on that 45 accepted answers with 0 upvotes could be banned?