# Newly registered users copy whole answers

Tags: support, users, plagiarism

In the past hour, I saw two new users who just copy and paste my answers without any modification. I've looked into their profiles and I saw that all their answers are just plain copies of someone else's answer.

These are their answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48682888/1227923

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48682015/1227923

I wonder what should I do in these cases? In the past, I've tried to call a moderator, when a guy who always copies my answers copied the code again and even [copied the whole sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48431091/1227923). But moderator did nothing about this and this guy is still just copying other users' answers.

**Update**

I've tried that what you've suggested and as result, I was punished by downvotes of the original solution that was stolen. Posted [the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363296/1227923) where I've added **four** links as evidence for one of two guys (the first one) where the guy steal whole sentence and code without even slightly modifying it. But he was not punished.

So, it really looks like it's Ok to steal on SO. There will be a lot of people who will protect the thief and people who will upvote his answer and downvote yours.

Comment: They are obviously trolling and need to have their account suspended

Comment: I mean, at least they're using the quote format right.

Comment: @Adelin yes, I have that thought. But what about the guys who copy the code from your answer all the time? I mean they're doing this to gain the rating for their profile and not for trolling. And it's quite annoying and it demotivates.

Comment: This is so blatant abuse that a mod flag is in order. If it gets declined come back here and we'll create a new policy for moderators to follow.

Comment: Worth nothing that perhaps they are not even real persons. It seems they are some kind of bots. Here's [a weird copy paste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48682503/3233388)

Comment: This reminds me of a topic that I opened a while back: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354845/should-an-answer-ban-happen-when-there-are-too-many-zero-score-posts. I understand now that there are a lot of edge cases and it can't be based only on statistics, but I think that a solution has to be found because more "farmers" appear everyday and they are almost impossible to detect when you are browsing through question.

Comment: Really looks like a bot: 13 answers in less than 30 minutes, all of them 100% copy from other answers with just slight formatting changes

Comment: @Adelin: Some answers copy formatting, some don't. Some add different text, some miss some text. It's too inconsistent and slow to be a bot.

Comment: @Adelin Hmm, that reminds me of [answer bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283095/158100) ...

Comment: User nuked already.

Comment: your last example is very interesting because quick comments on the answers posted by asker broke grace period which could help to find out who pladiarised by comparing timelines of [your](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48431049/timeline) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48431091/timeline) answer. But the comments timing seems just a tad unlucky for moderator to make sure who to blame - if I read timelines correctly there were several seconds when it was technically possible that you copied that sentence from another answer and not vice versa

Comment: @gnat if you'll look into the edits history, you'll see that the copied sentence was there 6 minutes before the guy added the same sentence to his answer by editing his answer.

Comment: unfortunately it's only you who knows that it was posted as-is 5 min before; anybody else has to assume that you could have edited it in 5 minutes after that. The only way to make quicker "public cut-off" would be to [break grace period by a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/165773), possibly followed by some dummy edit to make it visible in post history. To make matters worse, stupid system doesn't count author's comments so you'd have to set up a sock puppet with 50+ rep to do such comments

Comment: @gnat my point was that anyone can see that. Just look into the history of both answers.

Comment: if my reading of timelines is correct, another answer was posted a bit earlier than grace period of your answer ended, that's why others can only guess which direction was copying done. It is asker's comment under second answer that split it to two clearly visible revisions that makes it almost certain that they copied the sentence from you and not the other way 'round, but it's still seems not 100% guaranteed

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Simply down / delete-voting isn't enough.

Mod-flag these answers as plagiarism:

> #Plagiarism: This answer is copied from <link to other answer>

That way, these users get a mark on their profile, and the answer will get deleted.

Comment: down voting would only get reversed, there is too much to vote on ...

Comment: (I've taken the liberty to flag the answers this user has "written". The user should be taken care of soon enough)

Comment: The user is now deleted, along with their answers.

Comment: Mod flagging doesn't always work. I flagged an answer as a copy of mine and it was pending for (I believe months, could be several weeks) and then I think it got declined or aged away. It would be nice if it always worked, but sometimes they just ignore you even though it's obvious plagiarism.

Comment: In my experience, `#plagiarism` in a custom mod flag helps quite a bit.