# Recurring problem with copy pasting

Tags: support, plagiarism, grace-period, fastest-gun

I've recently [asked the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363118/newly-registered-users-copy-whole-answers) about the situation when some guys copy solutions and code from other developer's answers. And the answer was to downvote and to call a moderator. I've tried to do both but it didn't work for me.

I see a lot of new developers who copy solutions and code, but usually, it helps when I just ask them nicely to not do that.

But now there are two guys in Laravel part of SO who copy from other answers and who aren't gonna stop:

- The first one is a guy who even copied whole sentences. He changed nickname right after the last conversation about copying, I guess he wants to hide it or something. And he's definitely not going to stop: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48701597/laravel-using-view-composer-in-my-routes-with-htmlspecial-error/48701648#48701648), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705753/laravel-a-href-validation/48705846#48705846), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431038/laravel-hasmany-doesnt-rectrieve-values/48431091#48431091), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48584669/how-to-order-data-twice-but-make-the-firts-orderby-ineffective/48584829#48584829). I've called a moderator a couple of times.
- The second guy copied in the past. But today he copied my answer and I've decided to ask him not to do it. He said he didn't copy anything and that I need to relax. I've downvoted and called a moderator (as you guys did advice). The guy downvoted my answer too. But when the moderator came, he just deleted all the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48752874/laravel-cant-get-value-from-nested-collection/48752992#48752921).

  As result, some guys even upvoted his answer when they clearly see he copied it. And my original answer has 2 downvotes.

Honestly, I'm demotivated and upset because of all this stuff. That's just wrong. I mean it feels pretty bad when you're playing with code for 5-10 minutes and find a solution and then some guy just ctrv-c ctrl-v it. And I'd really want to see these guys are gone.

I wonder, why these accounts are not banned? I mean this is against the rules and people can clearly see who copy the answers all the time.

If these guys will not be banned, how this situation will be handled?

Comment: hmm... in the second case, why does his post appear before yours in the timeline? It appears as though his was nearly 4 minutes earlier than yours.

Comment: @KevinB It doesn't. OP's is 12:24, the accused is 12:27.

Comment: @KevinB he edited twice, please look into the history of edits. The solution for the answer is using `merge()`. The guy gave two wrong solutions (`pluck` and the edited and added `toArray()`). But when I've posted my answer with `merge()` the guy copied it (the 3rd edit) in like 4 minutes after I've posted the answer.

Comment: I see 18:15 for his, and 18:19 for yours, looking at the individual timelines for each of the answers.

Comment: @KevinB Wait, what are you looking at? All 5 examples linked here have the OP coming first.

Comment: @KevinB are you looking at the answer creation timestamp? You should look into edits history, the 3rd edit.

Comment: For cases where the answer is a single line of code and the different answers are posted in minutes of each other you're going to have a pretty hard time proving plagiarism, rather than that they independantly came to the same solution.  For more significant contributions, that becomes sufficiently implausible.

Comment: basically... if all you have is one instance where this specific user may have copied your answer, we can't really prove that the user didn't instead come up with it on their own. Even if the edit came several minutes later. The voting can certainly be looked at, I find it odd that you received two down and he received one up, but it's certainly not proof of any wrongdoing.

Comment: Regarding the second guy. Ok, it's one line solution, but some answers do not even have a code but only an idea, a solution to a problem. Is it normal to copy it then? And is it normal to copy one line solutions? Also, when I'll find other proofs in the past or in the future answers, what should I do? Should I contact someone to ask for a ban the guy? Or I should create a new question with links?

Comment: And what about the first guy?

Comment: All i see is coincidence for the first guy. And a lot of bullying. Looking through his answer history, he certainly answers questions without copying other answers, so i find it hard to believe that all of those instances were copy/paste answers. They're easy enough questions that he could have come to the same conclusions.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin It's not really about whether there's code or not, it's a question of how reasonable it is for another person to have independantly come up with the solution they posted.  How likely that is is dependant on how different it is from other posts, how much content is there, how much room there is for different solutions to the question (a question with only a single right answer is very likely to get different people suggesting that same single answer, after all), a history of plagiarism, and so on.  At some point there's enough circumstantial evidence for it to be acted on.

Comment: @Servy well, in this case, it's super clear that the guy didn't know the answer to that question because his first 2 solutions were about working with existing data and not changing the way how the data is created. If you'd know Laravel, you'd see this right away.

Comment: I can see downvotes and sympathy for the second guy. That's fine, I'll just keep saving the pieces of evidence as I did for the first guy. But what about the first guy? Will he be punished? Or nothing will happen?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin It's very common for people to post an incorrect answer and then fix it after someone (in this case, the OP) explains why it's wrong.  That's not a definitive sign of plagiarism.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin You said you flagged the content for moderation attention.  They'll deal with it.  Whatever consequences they determine to be appropriate will happen.  You haven't even indicated if the flags were handled yet.  If they haven't been, you need to be patient, if they have, then the moderator has already done whatever they feel is merited given the evidence at hand.

Comment: @Servy OP doesn't know Laravel. The question was about collections, he couldn't merge them and he ended up with simple arrays. Again, if you'd know the framework, you'd see what's going on there.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin That's quite the leap to make given that one person forgot one method in one line of code in one answer.  Maybe it's true, and maybe it isn't; either way, there's not enough evidence to know whether it's malicious plagiarism or just simple forgetfulness.  Lots of people have forgotten really simple and obvious things from answers because they thought they already included them, or misunderstood the question, or any number of other reasons.

Comment: Both users have significant activity under the Laravel tag.

Comment: @Servy I got it. What about the first one?

Comment: @KevinB what do you mean by that?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin *"OP doesn't know Laravel"* there's clear evidence that that isn't the case for either OP.

Comment: @KevinB if you'll look at both [guys upvotes/number of answers ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/laravel/topusers), you'll see they don't know Laravel. I know Laravel and I say the guy couldn't find the solution without my answer because he tried whole different thing. Oh, and I know Laravel because I'm [Top-1 Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/laravel/topusers) guy here. Top-1 in Russian Laravel community (Laravel.ru 4K+ users). I'm Certified Laravel Developer. I'm the author of the only Laravel Best Practices source (there is an old one which is about PHP, but called Laravel BP).

Comment: @KevinB I didn't say I'm best. You said it. What I'm saying is I know Laravel very well and it's obvious the guy didn't come up with the solution.

Comment: My point was, your knowledge of laravel does not give you the ability to identify the knowledge of other users whom you have no contact with other than questions/answers here. You don't know these users. you don't know what they do, what they know, how long they've been coding in what languages. You're making assumptions because they presented the same correct answer. Maybe they did copy, but if there is no track record of them doing so in the past and it's not word for word, you've got nothing. You can't prove it, nor can a moderator. All we're left with is you being rude in comments.

Comment: It's obvious that a moderator has already looked into this situation (the first op) and found nothing that needed to be actioned on.

Comment: @KevinB so, you're saying that the first guy didn't anything wrong? I've posted 4 links. In 2 of those answers, even sentences were copied. Will he not be punished?

Comment: I don't see any copied sentences, what am i missing?

Comment: @KevinB [If you have category_id column in the forum_post table, then this will load categories with their related posts.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48431091/1227923) I can see just one at the moment but there was another one. I'll look into this. Now, let's say one sentence was copied.

Comment: Why would he have copied the sentence without the code? but i do understand your concern with that one.

Comment: Don't give up! I regularly see new accounts copy-paste things as answers. The source isn't always other answers, they copy their "answers" from all over the net. Keep collecting evidence and flag as appropriate. Just yesterday I had another such flag deemed "helpful" and the copy-pasted answers got deleted.

Comment: @S.L.Barth what makes this thing interesting is one of the guys reported by OP has solid rep of few thousands iirc. It's difficult to tell for sure but if it is indeed happening that "stalker" figured a way to abuse grace period: just follow come prolific answerer (eg in feed), and post copied content while their answer is still within grace period so that it's impossible for others to tell in which direction copying was done

Comment: @gnat Ah yes, you pointed that out in the other thread, I believe. The devs should be able to see what happened during grace period, if it's logged. But I don't know if the mods can see that much. I like the idea you suggested in the other thread, to quickly comment to break the grace period.

Comment: Someone from this thread just followed one of the links and downvoted the original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48701648/1227923) and also one of my old [random answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35685433/1227923). I don't understand why all this happening. My answers got a lot of downvotes during past 2 days. I'm shocked. I feel like I'm the bad guy, like that was me who stole.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I don't think this will help because moderators can obviously see the facts of stealing. I mean the code, even the whole sentence was copied and nothing happened. I don't think there is any difference for moderators between 4 and 7 pieces of evidence.

Comment: In the case of copying a complete sentence, flag it as plagiarism pointing out explicitly that a whole sentence was copied. Mod action - even if it's only a warning - should *absolutely* be taken in that case; if your flag gets declined, come to Meta and demand to know why. None of the rest seems damning, though. If your entire answer to a question is [a tweak of a few characters from the asker's original code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48584758/1709587), you can't reasonably demand that nobody else offer the same solution and explain it differently.

Comment: @MarkAmery a few characters sometimes mean a solution to a problem. Like `merge` described before. And I don't think it's normal when someone posts your code in 3+ minutes after you've posted it and changes method name or variables names or formatting the code a bit. And I'm pretty sure no one from the downvoters here will like when someone will steal their solutions regularly.

Comment: @MarkAmery I've raised the flag but now when I click "flag" under the question, I can see "Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!". When I go to flags-summary page, I can see "pending" status. The flag was raised on 24 Jan. Also, the guy deleted the answer 2 days ago.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Since I don't play the FGITW game, I'm unlikely to ever experience such a thing. But you'll forgive me if *"Somebody **stole** the 10-character bugfix I came up with in 5 minutes"* isn't a complaint I take particularly seriously. You already have answer timestamps showing who posted first, and you can (and, in my view, should) downvote and comment on answers that essentially duplicate the approach from an earlier answer without adding extra value, but still, answers that take the same broad approach are allowed, and for trivial questions those will probably have identical code.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin You can still flag deleted posts, and should if they provide evidence of rule-violating behaviour, which plagiarism is. The "declined" flag message will be referring to some other flag on some other post, not the "pending" one. Possibly the UI is confusing/broken in the case where your last flag was declined AND you've already got a pending flag on the post you're trying to flag?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin And yes, some flags take a long time to get handled, unfortunately. I've got one I've been waiting for action on since January 10.

Comment: @MarkAmery I've retracted the old flag and flagged again. We'll see what will happen. Also, the flag was the only pending flag. All other old flags were reviewed on time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've reviewed all the cases mentioned here, and all of the flags that have resulted. Due to the absence of a few moderators, and an ongoing purge of voting rings, the queue of custom flags has built up a little bit. We're gradually working that down.

In the first case, it does look like some content was copied, due to identical or near-identical sentences being present in one or two answers. Those answers have been deleted. I'm not as sure about the others left by that user, because the presence of similar short amounts of code in answers left within minutes of one another isn't enough for me to decide anything conclusively here. In fact, I saw at least one case where they left an answer before you did, and you later posted similar code. From the comments they've received and the dogpile voting on their answers, I think they've been sufficiently chastised.

In the second case, I saw no evidence of plagiarism. In fact, they explained exactly how they arrived at their answer independently of you. The hostility you directed at them and the fight that resulted led to a number of these comments being flagged, which is why I wiped them first. In the future, I highly recommend flagging moderators with evidence of plagiarism and letting us review that first. If you're right, we'll take action, and if you've falsely accused someone that can be quietly dismissed.

[We take plagiarism seriously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299777/what-should-be-done-with-users-found-guilty-of-plagiarism/299784#299784) and act on multiple plagiarists a day. However, when all that we have to go on is similar-looking code, it can be much more difficult to separate copied code from independent solutions. This is particularly true when people are leaving answers within minutes of one another, as was the case here. Copied wording is another matter, and almost always indicates plagiarism. While there may only be one way in code to solve a problem, there's always different ways of phrasing an explanation.

Again, if you feel that someone is plagiarizing answers, use a custom moderator flag and point out what was copied. Focus on copied wording, larger blocks of code (bonus points if comments and nonfunctional whitespace are copied), and answers left long after another was placed on the question. Don't try to take the law into your own hands and make public accusations against someone, because that can lead to innocent people being targeted or to nasty comment and downvote fights.

Comment: Thanks. At least you've investigated this, that's really good. I'll also take away a couple of pieces of advice from this answer and comments above. I have a few questions though. 1. What should I do when someone's copying a solution and not the code? An example is `merge` discussed in comments. I've spent a few minutes by merging different Laravel collections in Laravel Tinker to find the solution. Should I just zip it when someone's copying stuff like that? I mean there is no a block of code here that can prove something. And the most of the guys above agreed that this was not stealing.

Comment: 2. What should I do if someone's posting a similar answer in 2-5 minutes after mine? Should I flag it somehow or just skip? I mean during the grace period many answers are copied and edited (copied then enhanced or changed the code).

3. You've said, "I saw at least one case where they left an answer before you did, and you later posted similar code". If my answer was posted later than 2 minutes after someone's similar answer, please let me see it.

4. I can see a lot of downvotes recently and it looks like it's related. What can I do about this except asking "Please explain the downvote"?

Comment: 5. Can a screenshot be a proof someone stole your answer? I mean when two guys posted different answers, I make a screenshot because I know this guy steals often and then the guy copies code from my answer. But because of grace period, noone can see that. Will this kind of screenshot be a proof?

Comment: For example, the same guy just posted [this](https://ibb.co/jNgqJ7). Should I flag it? I mean the solution is exactly the same and he just changed `auth()` to `Auth::` which are both shortcuts to the exactly the same functionality.