# Should we stop answering questions

Tags: discussion

I noticed many times a correct answer on Stack Overflow question that has no response from the asker even if the answer clearly solves the problem. Should we stop answering questions?

Do answers without any points contribute to asker getting blocked?

Comment: To stop answering questions on a question and answer site makes us 50% redundant.

Comment: Most of the value from the site isn't that it helps the person who asked the question, but the other readers later. Additionally, no response is *required* when a correct answer is posted.

Comment: What about blocking users?

Comment: @amitmahajan Why would we block users who have had neither a positive impact or a negative impact on the site?

Comment: Why someone will answer posts when people are not accepting/rejecting or replying to answers? what will encourage them?

Comment: @amitmahajan I don't know, maybe the fact that they want to help someone. Just because nobody responds with a comment/upvote/accept does not mean that the answer was not helpful. There are countless questions on this site with 100k+ views and only a few dozen upvotes on the top answer. Not everyone uses the tools they have to show gratification, either because they don't know how or don't care. If you only answer questions for the sake of earning reputation (both the virtual number and the recognition of your peers) then that's fine, but there are more reasons than just your own to do that.

Comment: Stop answering poorly asked and/or formatted questions. If a question is lousy, it's more likely the asker doesn't care about you and won't be bothered to follow up.

Answer (score 8):

If content is good, it should gets votes from other users, not just the asker.

> Doesn't answers without any points contribute to user getting blocked?

Not as far as we know. 0-scored questions don't, they are just neutral:

> **Zero-scored questions do not contribute to a ban**, but they don't move you away from it either
>
> -- [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351877/3155639)

Comment: So a person can post redundant answers without any issues.

Comment: @amitmahajan What do you mean by "redundant" answers? 0 scoring answers are fine. Multiple identical answers are not for other reasons.

Comment: redundant/spam posts

Comment: @amitmahajan Actual spam will get you banned for spamming.

Comment: @amitmahajan If you see questions/answers/comments that are quite clearly spam, then you should flag them immediately.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer:

**No**

Long answer:

**NOOOOOOO**

Okay let me address this piece by piece:

> I noticed many time correct answer on stackoverflow posts has no response from the person asking question even if the answer clearly resolves the problem

Many questions are asked by people who have joined Stack Overflow just to ask a question -- Actually, originally that's why I joined too. These people don't have enough rep to upvote, oftentimes don't know enough about the workings of the site to know that they can accept answers, and frequently close the page on Stack Overflow as soon as they've solved their issue, never to look back. Regardless of the circumstance, there may be many reasons why there is no response. Some people even comment "Thank you," which comments are frequently removed as they contribute nothing to the answer, so when you're looking back, perhaps the asker did attempt to thank the answerer and the comment was later deleted.

But regardless of the reasons for responding/acknowledging the people who answered their question, that shouldn't have anything to do with the question being useful for future readers. In a couple days or months or years, someone with the same issue will be googling (or binging if that ever gets popular enough) and will find that question, and find the answer to their question. At that point, it makes no difference to that user if the green "accepted" checkmark is present, or if there's a comment saying "Thanks that worked!", or any other response from the asker after the issue has been solved. All the searcher cares about is finding their answer, and if the question has been answered, then they did.

> should we stop answering questions?

I basically answered this in the last part, but to restate, No. Our answers have merit, first for the answer, and afterwards for other people with the same issue. This has nothing to do with the asker responding after the issue is solved.

> Doesn't answers without any points contribute to user getting blocked?

Actually they don't, and they shouldn't. Just because no votes have been cast doesn't mean it was a bad question or answer, perhaps it was a good question or answer but nobody with enough rep to vote has looked at that particular post.

Bad questions/answers should contribute to a user getting blocked, so if it is a bad question/answer, it should be downvoted, and being downvoted is part of what decides if the question/answer is going to contribute to the user getting blocked. I don't know all the workings of the algorithm, but until a person has looked at a post and has decided it is bad and has downvoted it, the algorithm cannot know if the post is good or bad and shouldn't make any contributions to the user being blocked.